# Exceptions with Jmeter Perfmon Metrics Collector

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am facing the below exception when I try to run the Jmeter Load testing.
I need to monitor the CPU and memory of Web and App servers so I have added the Perfmon Metrics Collectors and configured the Server agents on the Web and App Servers

Jmeter Version-3.1 is being installed

Jars added:
[image]

When I execute the Jmeter Application I face the below exception:

```
ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/perfmon/metrics/MetricParams
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.initiateConnector(PerfMonCollector.java:200)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.initiateConnectors(PerfMonCollector.java:175)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.perfmon.PerfMonCollector.testStarted(PerfMonCollector.java:126)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.testStarted(ResultCollector.java:348)
    at kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector.testStarted(CorrectedResultCollector.java:28)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:204)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:325)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.MetricParams
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Answer (score 1):

Now the Perfmon is working and i followed the below video tip

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-dHii9qZD0

And installed the Plugin - 
https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/file/JMeterPlugins-Standard-1.4.0.zip
The above plugins were missing and were not mentioned in the installation documents.